# Resync a makefile from an updated git submodule?

Tags: git, version-control

I have (hopefully) a relatively simple git question, but I'm a git newbie and don't understand all the vocabulary.

I am trying to update [R2D3](https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3/) to the latest version of D3.js. The repo's [owner has said that](https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3/issues/77) the steps are as follows:

1. Point the D3 submodule at the v3.0.6 (latest) tag.
2. Resync the makefile to include any additional files that were added/removed
3. Run tests to ensure nothing regressed.

I know how to do points 1 and 3, and have updated the submodule. The problem is that I don't know what "resync the makefile" in point 2 means!

I can see that there is a makefile at the core of the repo. Before I updated the submodule it ran ok, and now if I run `make` I now get the following error:

```
No rule to make target lib/d3/src/core/this.js, needed by r2d3.core.js. Stop.
```

So something clearly does need to be updated, but how do I sync the makefile and where from? Does this just mean 'edit it to match the new D3 makefile'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated R2D3 to point to the latest version of D3. Please check out v0.1.0

FYI: Resyncing the makefile means to take the latest makefile from D3 v3 and swap out the patched modules. You can see what i mean by this by comparing the D3 makefile with one in R2D3.